# Why http module is not located in the node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js

My question is what is the difference between `http` module and other modules in node.js . why is the `http` module not located in `./node_modules`?
Where I can find the module?

Comment: Its built in, like fs and the others your find [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `http` module is provided by your installation of Node.js. It's what's known as a [core module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules)

You can view the source to them in the repo (or download them locally): https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib

### Update

As of Node 18 you can reference core modules by prefixing them with `node:`, which ensures you don't load a dependency that shares the same name.

```js
const http = require('node:http');
```

Answer (score 2):

- HTTP modules are compiled into its binary distribution and load automatically when 
  Node.js process starts. but, you need to import the core module first in order to use it 
  in your application.
- `var http = require('http');`